# AppCode warning "Resource not found" when using Asset Catalog

Tags: ios, uiimage, appcode, asset-catalog

I have added an image set to the asset catalog (in Xcode) and then intended to access this in code.

[image]

The code I am using (in AppCode) is...

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Photo_Placeholder"];
```

I know this works and is correct. However, AppCode is telling me "Resource Not Found".

[image]

I know that this is only a warning and the build works anyway but I wondered if there is a way to get AppCode to recognise the names of the image sets in an Asset Catalog? At the moment it auto completes the image name based on the files not the image set name.

Comment: @Fogmester Btw, it should be fixed in the 2016.1.3 EAP we published today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the inconvenience, it's a known problem in current AppCode version. Please, follow [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-12437) in our tracker to receive updates.